# Spring Security concurrent session control per User group or per single user

Tags: spring, concurrency, spring-security

I am writing this question in order to understand how to control the number of the session that the user can have referred to Spring Security 
In spring i can define the maximum number of session that all users must have i.e. trough the session management i define for example that all users should not be allowed to have more then 3 session

```
.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(3)
```

That alone is not enough i.e. we need to give the servlet container  a way to notify spring security to update the session or delete the session etc. thus we need to configure HttpSessionEventPublishet

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

Now here is the question how do i configure something like that:
admin users should be allowed to have maximum number of session set to 8 session pro admin user, but regular users  should not be allowed to have more then one session per user.

Comment: Implement your own strategy based on the `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` class. You would need to override the `getMaximumSessionsForThisUser` method and implement your logic there. Then wire up your custom imlpementation with the `sessionmanagement` .

Comment: Deinum thank you for that response i will take a week to process that information and let you know if that is the answer, it seems plausible to me. Again thanks for the quick feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default strategy only allows to set a maximum session globally regardless of the user. The property is set on the class `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` which has a simple setter for that property.

The actual value is determined in the `getMaximumSessionsForThisUser` method which, in the default implementation, returns the value for the `maximumSession` property.

You would need to implement your own strategy by either implementing it fully yourself by creating a class that imlpements `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` or, easier, by creating a subclass of `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` which simply overrides the `getMaximumSessionsForThisUser` method.

```
public class CustomConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy {

    protected int getMaximumSessionsForThisUser(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean admin = // Check authentication.getAuthorities() for the admin role
        return admin ? 8 : 1;

    }
}
```

Then in your configuration create a `@Bean` for it and wire that bean to the `sessionManagement` section of the configuration.

```
@Bean
public CustomConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy sessionControlStrategy() {
    return new CustomConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}
```

Then in your security configuration code do something like

```
sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionControlStrategy());
```

Comment: M. Deinum  have now completed my test it works! Thanks again.

Comment: I wanted only to add the following I had to create a bean SessionRegistryImpl and pass that bean to the CustomConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy  constructor as i did not defined implicit default constructor, that is because ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy also does not have one.